# Are RSA-SHA256 signatures prone to length extension attacks?

Tags: rsa, signature, sha-256, sha-3, length-extension

I need to sign a message using a private key and verify the message with a public key, while making sure the message hasn’t been tampered.

I know that SHA-256 itself is prone to length-extension attacks.

I also know that things like HMAC have been specifically designed to circumvent such attacks.

But what if I sign a message with RSA and SHA-256? Are they safe?

Do I need to sign the RSA/SHA3 to be protected? Or maybe truncated versions of SHA2 (namely SHA-384 and SHA-512/256) which are allegedly *not* susceptible to length-extension attacks?

Would HMAC be a better approach to this problem?

I’m considering using RSA which is probably the most famous among asymmetric cryptography. Feel free to point me to something else if there’s a better option. I need something supported by OpenSSL and the Node.js crypto module (which, as far as I know, is also based on OpenSSL).

PS. I’m a bit new to the crypto community, so I hope my words make sense.

**-- addendum--**

Here is my concern about RSA-SHA256.

Let’s say the message is $M$ and its hash is $SHA256(M)$.

An attacker can use them to compute $M||X$ and $SHA256(M||X)$, even without knowing the private key. In this case, the recipient of $M||X$ and its signature $SHA256(M||X)$ shall believe that the message is valid because the message and its signature do match.

At least that’s what happens if RSA_sign simply uses the raw hash. If RSA passes the hash through a HMAC-like technique or any algorithm that prevents the attacker from forging a signature, I guess we’re safe.

Comment: A possible dupe of: [How can Hashed Value be same in length extension attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87696/18298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is HMAC needed for a SHA-3 based MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17735/is-hmac-needed-for-a-sha-3-based-mac)

Comment: @AleksanderCH thanks for the link. It partially answers the question. It shows that a SHA3-based MAC would be safe without a HMAC, which was one of my assumptions. But it doesn’t tell if RSA-SHA256 sign/verify is safe, which is my main question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Hashed Value be same in length extension attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87696/how-can-hashed-value-be-same-in-length-extension-attack)

Comment: @kelalaka that’s an interesting read about how length-extension attacks work, but it doesn’t tell if RSA-SHA256 is susceptible to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what if I sign a message with RSA and SHA-256? Are they safe?

Length extension attacks are not a concern.

Here is what a length extension attack allows you do to: if you are given the hash $\text{SHA256}(M)$, but you don't know the original message $M$ (but you do know its length), then you can compute the value of the hash $\text{SHA256}(M || X)$ (where $||$ is bitstring concatenation, and for some values of the string $X$); the value of this hash will be different than the original hash.

So, why isn't this a concern:

- When you have a signature of a known message $M$, you obviously know $M$; you can (should you want) compute $\text{SHA256}(M || X)$ for any string $X$ you want; you don't need a "length extension attack"
- RSA signs the value $\text{SHA256}(M)$; the value $\text{SHA256}(M || X)$ will be different, and so if you replace $M$ with $M || X$, the signature will not verify

Comment: My concern is, the attacker knows `M` and `SHA256(M)`, so he may compute `M||X` and `SHA256(M||X)` (even without knowing the private key). In this case, the recipient of `M||X` and its signature `SHA256(M||X)` will not know that the message was tampered because the altered message and its signature will match. Well, at least that’s what happens if RSA_sign simply uses the raw hash. If RSA passes the hash through a HMAC-like technique, I guess we’re safe.

Comment: @vdavid: "so he may compute `M||X` and `SHA256(M||X)` (even without knowing the private key)." - how is that different from (say) SHA3?  With SHA3, if he knows $M$ and selects $X$, he can compute `SHA3(M||X)`.  If you're thinking that `SHA256(M||X)` will be the same value as `SHA256(M)`, well no, that's not how it works.

Comment: @vdavid: Your _"the recipient of `M||X` and its signature `SHA256(M||X)`…"_ is in error.  `SHA256(M||X)` is not the signature of `M||X`. It's an intermediary step in computing a signature of `M||X`, as a function of `SHA256(M||X)`, private key, optional randomness. Among the three inputs of this function, only the private key is secret. Thus it is not an issue that `SHA256(M||X)` is easy to compute; it's a functional requirement.

Comment: @poncho SHA3 is theoretically better because, unlike SHA-256, I think we *cannot* use `M` and `SHA3(M)` to forge a `SHA3(M||X)`

Comment: @fgrieu OK if the hash is an intermediate step, I guess the signature cannot be tampered

Comment: @vdavid: you are correct that SHA3, unlike SHA-256, has no length-extension property. However you are incorrect in what that prevents. It prevents computing `SHA3(M||X)` from `SHA3(M)` _unless_ one has complete knowledge of `M` (in the case of SHA-256, one further needs to restrict to some `X` with precisely the right start, dependent on the length of `M`). With knowledge of `M`and `X` one can compute `SHA3(M||X)`, for any `M` and `X`. Note: the Right Thing will be to accept poncho's answer by clicking on the tick.

Comment: @fgrieu You’re right. And because `M` is not secret in my case, I believe this property doesn’t give SHA3 a significant advantage over SHA-256 (at least, not from a length-extension point of view).

Comment: Actually it should be $\text{SHA256}(M || padding_1|| X)$ since the original hash has a padded and during extension SHA-256 calculates another padding.

Comment: @kelalaka: actually, I had included $padding_1$ in the $X$ - that's why I said it was for 'some X' - I didn't think the details of the length-extension attack was actually relevant - he's not attempting to perform the attack, instead, he is asking about the implications.

Comment: $M$ is the message that is free for all to verify the signature with it, Imho, this detail is still important.

Comment: @kelalaka I’d say the padding matters if the wrong padding makes RSA vulnerable to forge a valid signature for a tampered message. Is it something I should be concerned with?

Comment: @vdavid: *padding* is being used in two different senses; one is some padding done as a part of the SHA256 computation (which is a detail that you don't need to be concerned with, unless you're implementing SHA256).  The other is padding done after the hash and just before the raw RSA computation - that is important (getting it wrong would allow someone to generate forgeries), however it has nothing to do with length-extension attacks.

Comment: @poncho what kind of other forgeries could happen if I use the wrong padding? Is there a recommended padding? I’ve yet to choose one among PKCS (or any other that would be better for RSA).